# Dates and rules

Tags: rules

I've got a rule with php condition. I'm trying to compare 2 dates. the problem comes from the node date.

Here is a part of my script:

```
$date= date("Y-m-d");
$node_date= ("[node:field_event_date]");

$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $node_date);
echo $myDateTime->format("d-m-Y");
```

I would like to convert my date and time to a different date format (d-m-Y was set on purpose to test the script, but eventually the format would be Y-m-d).

The date i'm pulling out has this format: yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s (i did an echo $node_date ) 
but i can't convert it using "createFromFormat". 
Even though when i enter a date with the same format that "$node_date", instead of the variable, it works...

So i don't really know any more what to do...i feel i got the solution, but cannot make it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my solution is actually going to help, but I had a similar issue not with the node date but with a date field in a content type.

For some reason I was not able to properly expose the date field for comparison, and there are some slightly relevant issues about this in Rules issue queue. So what I did was to expose the field using the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module.

Although this is just a work-around really, with a performance penalty, it turned out to me that with this way the exposed field could then be used directly in comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll check out and let you know !